# What is the name of this formula?

Tags: geometry

There is 3d angle addition formula for which I would like to know what it is called in the literature:

Given two vectors $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$ at (physicist's) angles $(\theta_1,\,\phi_1)$ and $(\theta_2,\,\phi_2)$, the angle $\Theta$ between the two vectors is given by:

$$\cos \Theta=\cos \theta_1 \cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)$$

What is the name of this formula?

Comment: It looks an awful lot like the [Spherical Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines).

Comment: This is the name I was looking for!  Thanks, Blue!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, my comment answered the question. I'll convert the comment to a formal answer in order to get the question out of the Unanswered queue.

> The formula looks an awful lot like the [Spherical Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the name of the formula, but it is derived from the dot product in spherical coordinates. See this pdf:
http://people.wku.edu/david.neal/117/Unit5/MoreSpherical.pdf